# Como inserir um else para exibir mensagem no caso de não ter arquivos para upload

Tags: php

**Código**

```
<?php
$files = $obj->field('upload');

foreach ($files as $file)
  {
    $file_url = get_attached_file($file['id']);
    echo '<a href="' . $file["guid"] . '">' . $file["post_title"] . '</a>';
    echo '<br>';
  }
?>
```

Mensagem de erro quando não tem anexo:

> Warning: Invalid argument
>   supplied for foreach() in
>   /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/pods/components/Templates/Templates.php(500)
>   : eval()'d code on line 8

Comment: A variável `$obj` é uma instância de que classe? Poste um pouco mais do código.

Comment: Verifique se `$files` tem algum elemento, pode usar o `count()` ;)

Comment: Esse é a parte do codigo que chamo dentro do template do pods

Comment: <tr>
 <td>
  <?php 


  $files = $obj->field('upload');

  foreach ( $files as $file ) {
    $file_url = get_attached_file($file['id']);
    echo '<a href="' . $file["guid"] . '">' . $file["post_title"] . '</a>';
    echo '<br>';
  }
  ?>
  
 </td>
 <td>{@objeto}</td>
 <td>{@abertura}</td>
 <td>{@valor_da_gru}</td>
 <td>{@fase}</td>
</tr>

Comment: eu nao saco muito por isso tenho dificuldades ate de explicar.

Comment: @Rodrigo, o que a função emtpy faz é verificar se uma variável está vazia, literalmente - [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

Answer (score 2):

Para o seu caso, acredito que é bem simples:

```
<?php

$files = $obj->field('upload');
if (!empty($files)) {
    foreach ( $files as $file ) {
             $file_url = get_attached_file($file['id']);
             echo '<a href="' . $file["guid"] . '">'
                  . $file["post_title"]
                  . '</a>';
                  . '<br>';
    }
} else {
   echo "Não há arquivos enviados!";  die();
}
```

Mas eu sugiro fazer algo mais bem trabalhado, usando exceção:

```
function listFiles()
{
  $file = func_get_args(0);
  try {

      if (empty($file)) {
         throw new Exception("Não há arquivo(s) enviado(s)!");
      }
       $content = '';
      foreach ( $files as $file ) {
         $file_url = get_attached_file($file['id']);
         $content.= '<a href="' . $file["guid"] . '">'
                    . $file["post_title"]
                    . '</a>';
                    . '<br>';
      }
      return $content;

  } catch (Exception $e)  {
     return $e->getMessage();
  } 
} 

echo listFiles($obj->field('upload'));
```

Comment: Obrigado do seu Código eu cheguei ao empty.

Answer (score 1):

Utilize um `isset` ou `empty` para verificar que essa variável/array possui valores.

```
<?php
$files = $obj->field('upload');

if(!empty($files)){
foreach ($files as $file)
  {
    $file_url = get_attached_file($file['id']);
    echo '<a href="' . $file["guid"] . '">' . $file["post_title"] . '</a>';
    echo '<br>';
  }
} else {
 print "Nenhum ficheiro selecionado";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer uma verificação simples em `$files`:

```
<?php

$files = $obj->field('upload');
if (count($files)) {
    foreach ( $files as $file ) {
    $file_url = get_attached_file($file['id']);
    echo '<a href="' . $file["guid"] . '">' . $file["post_title"] . '</a>';
       echo '<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu testei e apresentou um erro:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/pods/components/Templates/Templates.php(500) : eval()'d code on line 15

Comment: Só deixe claro para o Rodrigo, que usando `count()`, ele não eximirá os arquivos, mas irá listar todos os arquivos quando tiver pelo menos um na coleção.

Comment: Ainda em tempos falei disso, um isset/empty seria mais proveitoso.

Comment: Bem galera eu resolvi com ( empty ) Ela serve para saber se uma variável existe


<?php 

  $files = $obj->field('upload');
  if(!empty($files)):
   
 foreach ( $files as $file ) {
  $file_url = get_attached_file($file['id']);
  echo '<a href="' . $file["guid"] . '">' . $file["post_title"] . '</a>';
  echo '<br>';
  }

else:

    echo "No content found.";


endif;
  ?>